# How to fix error due to ascii conversion of uint8_t variable

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I am trying to implement logic using flags such that flag variables value will be 0 or 1 only.  So I initialise a `uint8_t` variable with 0, but when I debug I found its converted to 0x30 (which is ASCII value of 0) so my later logic fails

```
uint8_t flag_count = 0;

if(flag_count == 0)
{
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 1000)
    {
        counter = 0;
        flag_count = 1;
    }
}

if(flag_count == 1)
{
    //do something
    flag = 0;
}
```

so when I run program flag_count value is 0x30 (ASCII value of '0') and hence counter never increments, so the logic fails.

I tried

```
uint8_t flag_count = 0x00;
```

it still does the same thing.

Comment: No sane compiler would do that. This is certainly a memory corruption issue somewhere else in the code.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you show that would cause that behaviour. What else is going on? What's the scope of `flag_count`?

Comment: My supposition: the code you show to us is not the same which gives the issue. Can you show the exact code? Also the disassembly if available.

Comment: Why would you not use a true Boolean variable of type `_Bool` (or `bool` if you include stdbool.h)?

Comment: "when I debug" - Exactly how are you doing that?  Sounds like flawed debugging to me - causing you to draw incorrect conclusions.

Comment: Are you accepting value for `flag_count` from serial port? Unless configured, most terminal programs send ASCII value from a computer.

Comment: Please show us a completely source that can be compiled.

Answer (score -1):

for uint8_t :compiler was taking it as char and hence converting it to ascii

so i need to use uint32_t or int to make it work :)